# How can i make all the created Spheres objects in the Hierarchy to be under the Terrain?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now when it's creating the Spheres i see them all on the Hierarchy on the right.
But i want to to see them under/inside the Terrain so only if i will click on the Terrain it will expand all the Spheres:

[image: Spheres]

I don't want to see all the 100 Spheres in the Hierarchy but to put them under/insde the Terrain or under/insde other GameObject so if i click on it it will expand all the 100 Spheres in the Hierarchy on the left.

This is the script:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class SphereBuilder : MonoBehaviour
{
    // for tracking properties change
    private Vector3 _extents;
    private int _sphereCount;
    private float _sphereSize;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How far to place spheres randomly.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector3 Extents;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How many spheres wanted.
    /// </summary>
    public int SphereCount;

    public float SphereSize;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // prevent wrong values to be entered
        Extents = new Vector3(Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.x), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.y), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.z));
        SphereCount = Mathf.Max(0, SphereCount);
        SphereSize = Mathf.Max(0.0f, SphereSize);
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        Extents = new Vector3(250.0f, 20.0f, 250.0f);
        SphereCount = 100;
        SphereSize = 20.0f;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        UpdateSpheres();
    }

    private void UpdateSpheres()
    {
        if (Extents == _extents && SphereCount == _sphereCount && Mathf.Approximately(SphereSize, _sphereSize))
            return;

        // cleanup
        var spheres = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Sphere");
        foreach (var t in spheres)
        {
            if (Application.isEditor)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(t);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(t);
            }
        }

        var withTag = GameObject.FindWithTag("Terrain");
        if (withTag == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Terrain not found");

        for (var i = 0; i < SphereCount; i++)
        {
            var o = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            o.tag = "Sphere";
            o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(SphereSize, SphereSize, SphereSize);

            // get random position
            var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x, Extents.x);
            var y = Extents.y; // sphere altitude relative to terrain below
            var z = Random.Range(-Extents.z, Extents.z);

            // now send a ray down terrain to adjust Y according terrain below
            var height = 10000.0f; // should be higher than highest terrain altitude
            var origin = new Vector3(x, height, z);
            var ray = new Ray(origin, Vector3.down);
            RaycastHit hit;
            var maxDistance = 20000.0f;
            var nameToLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain");
            var layerMask = 1 << nameToLayer;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxDistance, layerMask))
            {
                var distance = hit.distance;
                y = height - distance + y; // adjust
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Terrain not hit, using default height !");
            }

            // place !
            o.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        }

        _extents = Extents;
        _sphereCount = SphereCount;
        _sphereSize = SphereSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: whateverGO.ransform.parent = otherGO.transform; to create a hierarchy in editor. This also make LocalScale a thing. BTW watch out with DestroyImmediate, there's no guarantee it happens to the next frame (write a small test app. and check null status of just destroyed GO), so TBH I didn't find it any different than the plain old Destroy

Comment: @Mark Might be worth adapting that into an answer - I think it's complete enough to meet the OP's needs.

Comment: I found how to put the Spheres under the Terrain: o.transform.parent = GameObject.Find ("Terrain").transform; But aobut the DestroyImmediate i'm not familiar with it. What and how should i handle it ?

Comment: @Mark hope you don't mind me using your comment to derive an answer.

Comment: @XanderLuciano nope. enjoy. ninja it :)

Comment: @TheLostLostit check the answer provided by Xander, adding that Find() is slow, better use it one time only, if you really, really must use it. As of your question, use Destroy() instead and don't expect the GO being destroyed as soon as the code runs, but whenever the system likes (so store somewhere it's gone, etc)

Comment: @Mark I don't really must use it with the Spheres just thought it will be nicer to put it as childs instead see 100 Spheres in the Hierarchy. It's better not to do it with the Spheres ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all the gameobjects in the scene, and set their parent as the terrain if their name is sphere:

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject terrain = GameObject.Find("Terrain");
    foreach (var obj in FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject[])
    {
        if(obj.name == "sphere")
            obj.transform.parent = terrain;
    }
}
```

Comment: Xander small changes: instead "sphere" it should be "Sphere" and second i added this code in the Update() function after calling the UpdateSpheres() function. If i put it in the Start function it will not work.

Comment: You should use this function sparingly, the `Find` function is pretty resource intensive. If you find you need it every `Update()` because objects are being `instantiated`, you should just set the parent when the objects are being `instantiated`, as well as putting the `terrain` variable in the `start` function so it only needs to run that line once.